# $scope is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.a = 0;
    $scope.find = function() {
    $scope.a += 1;
  }
}])

.directive('myLoading', [function() {

if ($scope.a % 2 === 0) {
    return {
        template: "<div>Hi</div>"
    }
} else {
    return {
        template: ''
    }
}
}]);
```

I'm trying to manipulate the DOM every time I recieve a click event from a button. This is supposed to make a switch between the templates each time I recieve the click. But I'm getting an error in the console log. `$scope is not defined`, the one in the directive.

Comment: That's because you haven't defined $scope in your directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**$scope inside controller and $scope inside directive aren't the same variable.**

There's many ways to communicate between controller and directive. For example directives attribute's value, but you can also use $broadcast / $emit, or $rootScope.

[More info.](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/)

Answer (score 1):

You could not directly access the `$scope` variable **OR** `$scope` dependency inside directive factory function. You could access the `scope` of that element inside `link` function of directive, but its depends on `scope` property of directive.

The thing which you wanted to achieve is much easier than what you are trying.

**Directive**

```
.directive('myLoading', [function() {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-if="(a % 2 === 0)">Hi</div>'
    }
}]);
```